# Crystal reports for VS2010 on Server2008R2 error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, installation, windows-server-2008-r2

I am getting the following error on one of our servers where I installed CR for VS2010: "Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0" I look in windows\assembly and I can see it there and it is the correct version, correct Public key and there are no other versions of CR in there.

I installed "CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0.zip" The same report works on our dev and production server but this problem is on our QA server. All servers are the same and I cannot see the difference. Any help? there are a lot of articles with this error but not one that helps me.

On the servers that work we do not have any reference to CR in the web.config, if that is of any help.

Thank you
Jack

Comment: I found the answer!! All I need to install on server2008R2 is: "CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0.zip" My mistake is that I went to the advanced settings of the application pool that the site was using and I set "Enable 32 bit applications" to true (as per a posting I found) As soon as I changed it to false everything started working!!! Come to think of it, it makes sense that if you installed the 64 bit redistributable then you do not need 32 bit in your app pool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer!! All I need to install on server2008R2 is: "CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0.zip" My mistake is that I went to the advanced settings of the application pool that the site was using and I set "Enable 32 bit applications" to true (as per a posting I found)

As soon as I changed it to false everything started working!!! Come to think of it, it makes sense that if you installed the 64 bit redistributable then you do not need 32 bit in your app pool? Also, I did not have any Crystal in my web.config (I did not need it, the dll was in the GAC-I could see it) I looked into c:\Windows\assemblies and I found all the Crystal in the - all version 13.0.2000